Netflix DGS codegen unresolved reference to scalar
I have this kotlin value class:
@JvmInline
value class UserId(val id: UUID)

And I'm trying to build a Netflix DGS scalar for it but the codegen isn't importing the class. I have written the scalar class and annotated it:
@DgsScalar(name="UserId")
class UserIdScalar: Coercing<UserId, String> { ... }

And added the typeMapping:
tasks.withType<com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask> {
    generateClient = true
    packageName = "com.example.demo.generated"
    typeMapping = mutableMapOf(
        "UserId" to "com.example.demo.UserId"
    )
}

But the generated code still has Unresolved reference: UserId errors. Really scratching my head, this sort of thing seems to work in other projects I have.

I was using the scalar in a union type, which isn't legal GraphQL.
union Approver = UserId

scalar UserId

Netflix DGS should probably throw an error on codegen for this case, it was trying to generate code for this case but failing to do the import.
